# How can I display images in a Word file when downloaded from html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ms-word

I tried to export HTML content to a Word document, and everything came in the proper format except for the image. Can you help me export the image to my Word document and ensure that it is properly displayed?
I tried some way but that did not work you can check the code for that and let me know how can I fix this issue.
Thank you.

I am receiving images in two ways: one in base64 format and the other as a URL.

you can see CodeSandBox Link for reference. [CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-snow-pfv4v8?file=/demo.tsx)

```
    exportToWord(element, filename = '', removeElement) {
    const body = document.getElementById(element);
    const clone = body.cloneNode(true);
    const removeChildElements = clone.querySelectorAll(removeElement);
    removeChildElements.forEach((el) => el.remove());

    const css =
      'table{border-collapse:collapse} th{border:1px gray solid;width:7em;padding:2px;} td{border:1px gray solid;width:7em;padding:2px;}';
    const header = `<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Export HTML to Word Document</title><style>
      ${css}
      </style></head><body>`;
    const footer = '</body></html>';
    const images = clone.querySelectorAll('img');
    images.forEach((img) => {
      const src = img.getAttribute('src');
      if (src.startsWith('data:image')) {
        // Image source is base64-encoded
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

          const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          const data = dataUrl.split(',')[1];

          // Replace image source with base64-encoded image data
          img.src = `data:image/png;base64,${data}`;
        });
        image.src = src;
      } else if (src.startsWith('http') || src.startsWith('//')) {
        const image = new Image();
        image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'; // Set crossOrigin attribute to allow CORS
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
          // Convert the image to a base64 data URL
          const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

          const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          const data = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
          // Replace the image source with the base64-encoded data URL
          img.src = `data:image/png;base64,${data}`;
        });

        // Get the original image source relative to the document location
        const originalSrc = new URL(src, document.location).href;

        // Set the image source to the original URL
        image.src = originalSrc;
      }
    });

    const html = header + clone.innerHTML + footer;

    const blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
      type: 'application/msword',
    });

    /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename ? `${filename}.doc` : 'document.doc';

    // Create a temporary anchor element
    const tempAnchor = document.createElement('a');

    // Set the href and download attributes
    tempAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    tempAnchor.download = filename;

    // Programmatically click the anchor element to trigger the download
    tempAnchor.click();

    // Clean up the temporary anchor element
    URL.revokeObjectURL(tempAnchor.href);
  },
```